# Как вызвать метод из другого класса минуя конструктор в PHP?

Tags: php

При попытке вызвать статический метод другого класса, вызывается его конструктор.
Как можно его вызвать, и как вызвать не статический метод также минуя конструктор(если возможно...)

```
class Test{
  public function __construct(Data $data){
    echo $data;
   }
  public static function getId(){
    return "Типо id";
  }
}

class NoTest{

   $text = Test::getId(); // вызывает конструктор => приводит к ошибке
   echo $text;
}
```

Comment: именно в таком виде код не компилируется. Но если последние две строки завернуть в функцию, то все работает и конструктор не вызывается. Может покажите полный пример?

Answer (score 2):

Статический метод ничего не знает о конструкторе и может быть вызван откуда угодно. У Вас ошибка в Вашем классе NoTest, перенесите это:

```php
$text = Test::getId(); // вызывает конструктор => приводит к ошибке
echo $text;
```

в отдельный метод и увидите, что всё работает:

```php
class Data {}

class Test
{
    public function __construct(Data $data) {
        echo $data;
    }
    
    public static function getId() {
        return "Типо id";
    }
}

class NoTest {
    public function getNoTestData() {
        print_r(Test::getId());
    }
}
    

$noTestObject = new NoTest();
print_r($noTestObject->getNoTestData()); // Выведет "Типо id"

print_r(Test::getId()); // Выведет "Типо id"
```